# How do I use specify zero or more repeating groups in a T-SQL LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I'm trying to pattern match something using `LIKE`. The below isn't my actual problem, but say I want one or more repetitions of a group of characters, for instance digits or comma (may be different groups of characters).

Matching a single digit or comma would be `'[0-9,]'`, but what if I want to match against one or more repetitions?

I've tried `'[0-9,]'` and `'[0-9,]*'`, but `*` matches a single wildcard. Effectively my question is how do I repeat a sequence in `LIKE`?

Comment: `[0-9,][0-9,][0-9,][0-9,][0-9,]`.

Comment: *"but `*` matches a single wildcard"* No it doesn't, `*` matches the character `*`. An underscore (`_`) is a single character wildcard, and percent (`%`) is the multi-character wilcard.

Comment: In SQL, the language, `LIKE` doesn't use regular expression syntax. Other databases have custom regular expression operators but SQL Server doesn't have that feature

Comment: @GSerg and Panagiotis - I think collectively this answers my question. Going to need to parse one char at a time. Thanks s much for your help.